# Storing 16 bytes of String array in 4 bytes memory, (compression) in RFID Tags

Tags: c#, .net

I hope that this question will not produce some vagueness. Actually I am working on RFID project and I am using Passive Tags. These Tags store only 4 bytes of Data, 32bits. I am trying to store more information in String in Tag's Data Bank. I searched the internet for String compression Algorithms but I didn't find any of them suitable. Someone please guide me through this issue. How can I save more data in this 4 bytes Data Bank, should I use some other strategy for storing, if yes, then what? Moreover, I am using C# on Handheld Window CE device.

I'll appreciate if someone could help me...

Comment: There is obviously no compression that can reduce arbitrary 16 byte values to 4 byte values.

Comment: thanks for these valuable answers. All I have to maintain a dictionary about data which is being written in Tag's Data Bank.

Comment: Is that comment a question or an answer?  You can use Dictionary Int32, String but that is not compression.  What is Data Bank?

Comment: Data Bank is actually the 4 byte memory in Tag (Tag's Vendor call it as Data Bank). Tag has its unique id.

Answer (score 1):

It  depends on  your tag, for example alien  tag http://www.alientechnology.com/docs/products/Alien-Technology-Higgs-3-ALN-9662-Short.pdf  ,  has  EPC  memory ,  I  think you  use  your  EPC  memory but You  can  also use  User Memory in  your  tag. You  don't  have to  compress  anything,  just  use your User Memory. Furthermore, technically I  rather not to save many data on my tag, I use my own coding on 32 bit and relates(map) it to the more Data  on my Software, and save my data on my Hard Disk. It is more safe too.

Comment: yes, I am using Alien Tags, there are EPC and User Memories. I am writing data on User Memory that is 4 bytes, Now I will follow you technique. thanx for the help....

Answer (score 0):

A compression scheme can't guarantee such high compression ratios.

The only way I can think of with 32-bits is to store an `int` in the 32-bits, and construct a **local/remote URL** out of it, which points to the actual data.

You could also make the `stored value` point to entries in a **local look-up table** on the device.

Comment: A compression scheme can't guarantee any compression ratio better than the identity transform for arbitrary data.

Answer (score 0):

There is obviously no compression that can reduce arbitrary 16 byte values to 4 byte values. That's mathematically impossible, check the [Pidgeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) for details.

Store the actual data in some kind of database. Have the 4 bytes encode an integer that acts as a key for the row your want to refer to. For example by using an auto-increment primary key, or an index into an array. Works with up to 4 billion rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you have less than 2^32 strings, simply enumerate them and then save the strings index (in your "dictionary") inside your 4 byte "Data Bank".

Answer (score 0):

Unless you know a lot about the format of your string, it is impossible to do this. This is evident from the [pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle): you have a theoretical 2^128 different 16-byte strings, but only 2^32 different values to choose from.

In other words, no compression algorithm will guarantee that an arbitrary string in your possible input set will map to a 4-byte value in the output set.

It may be possible to devise an algorithm which will work *in your particular case*, but unless your data set is sufficiently restricted (at most 1 in 79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,336 possible strings may be valid) *and* has a meaningful structure, then your only option is to store some mapping externally.

Comment: Ok, if I use external Mapping, saving my string in Database, and id of that particular string in Tag's Data Bank. but Tags has its unique Id, I can use Tag's ID for external mapping. I want to utilize this 4 byte memory. I was thinking that place some information in this Data Bank i.e. Asset ID + Asset Description (Asset is that container or some box on which this Tag will be clasped). that will help others to query the box with RFID reader.